# Not getting readyKey on NIO connection disconnection

Tags: java, networking, nio

I get a very strange NIO behavior, on very rare occasions I don't get selected readyKey on disconnection (due to VM kill) when I call select() as followed:

```
while (selector.isOpen()){
    selector.select(SELECT_TIMEOUT);
    Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
    if(!readyKeys.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Selected...");
    }
}
```

The key is registered as followed:

```
key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

OS: CentOS 6.2

VM: XEN

Java: JDK_1.6u17

Keep_ALIVE is set to run every 1sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the connection terminates due to keepalive failure, it is reset, not closed normally, so no FIN is delivered, so there is no 'readable' event. In this circumstance the only way to discover the disconnection would be via an IOException when writing, or by the *absence* of a read event, i.e. essentially a read timeout.

Don't set keepalive to run every second. It is extremely wasteful.

Comment: Thanks! I also tried to close the socket while it was registered on the selector and still didn't get any readable evet, is that also expected?

Comment: @GuyKorland If you close your own socket you won't get a selection event. You can't, because the key gets cancelled and is invalid if it even gets into the selected set, but there is no event for it to be selected on. Events come from the socket send and receive buffers: the receive buffer has data or EOS, or the send buffer has room.

Comment: 1. How can I check if a socket was reset by keepalive when working in Async mode? (without writing or reading from the socket) e.g. will socket.isClosed() or socketChannel.isClosed() return true?

2. What about using blocking io? will waiting socketChannel.read(buffer) will throw an exception on keepalive socket reset (i.e. which occurred after the read was started)?

Comment: @GuyKorland (1) Basically you can't other than by reading to writing. Those APIs are about the channel state, not the connection state: they tell you what *you* have done to the *`SocketChannel`* object. (2) In blocking mode you can use a read timeout, via `Socket.setSoTimeout()`. You need to be doing writes to provoke anything else, i.e. an `IOException: connection reset`.

Comment: I ran couple more tests and it seems like I the Selector do get READREADY on KEEP_ALIVE reset. It seems like the issue was due to explicit socket close which in turn removed the key from the Selector.